# Mapping Versions of vscode extension ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers to its Source Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, devcontainer

I've been exploring the ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers extension for Visual Studio Code and am interested in understanding its linkage to the devcontainers organization on GitHub.

Previously, the source code for this extension was housed in the repository https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers. However, since they deprecated that repo and move to https://github.com/devcontainers, I'm finding it challenging to map specific versions of the ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers extension back to its corresponding source code.

My primary questions are:

How can we trace back a specific version of the ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers extension to its respective source code in the devcontainers GitHub organization?
Has there been any change in the repository structure or repo organization conventions that might affect this mapping?
Are there any documentation or release notes that provide insights into these linkages for each version?

After I download the [vsix](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/ms-vscode-remote/vsextensions/remote-containers/0.318.0/vspackage) file and unzip it, I find the package.json. Based on this json file, I find:

1. npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vscode/dev-container-cli/v/0.292.0; from this npm page, I still cannot find the source code of this package.
2. inside the readme.md from the vsix, it says it will use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@devcontainers/cli?activeTab=versions in future.

But back to this question, it seems this extension is not that "open source"

Answer (score 0):

It appears the extension is not currently open source.

> The Visual Studio Code Remote Development extensions and their related components use an open planning, issue, and feature request process, but are not currently open source. The extensions share source code which is also used in fully managed remote development services like GitHub Codespaces and their related extensions.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/faq#_why-arent-the-remote-development-extensions-or-their-components-open-source